# in C++ files: what a file opened as an ios::binary differs from one opened as ios::binary | ios::out?

Tags: c++, fstream

if i opened a file like:

```
ofstream file("file.dat",ios::binary);
```

or

```
ofstream file("file.dat",ios::binary | ios::out);
```

what can i do with a file opened in the latter form that i can't do with the former form and vice versa

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for all people who answered me:
i now tested several codes depending on what i have been answered and came up with this summary:

**using ofstream:**
ios::out is the default even if nothing is specified, but if you used only ios::in with ofstream, no compilation  errors (unless you use read() or >> or some ifstream object) but no files would be written.

**using ifstream:**
ios::in is the default even if nothing is specified, but if you used only ios::out with ifstream, no compilation  errors (unless you use write() or << or some ofstream object) but you can't read any information from the file.

**using fstream:**
no defaults, you have to explicitly determine what you are going to do. Otherwise, no compilation error but you don't get what you want simply.

as for the original question , both work exactly  the same!

Answer (score 5):

For an ofstream, `ios::out` is the default, so there's no difference. I believe the only time specifying ios::out makes a difference is if you use an fstream, which can be opened for reading or writing, or both.

Comment: no 
if you use an fstream, you can write neither ios::out nor ios::in  and you'll still be able to write and read from the file..
so isn't it always the same writing of not writing ios::out ?

Comment: @I.m.engineer:I'd have to check to be sure, but if memory serves an fstream is opened for both input and output by default, but if you specify ios::out, it's opened only for output, and if you specify ios::in, it's opened only for input. That's going from memory though, to it's definitely not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases I would expect there to be no difference, though it seems like this could technically be implementation specific.

In my implementation (gcc 3.4.3) the open for the ofstream uses the ios:::out mode in the ofstream->open() call regardless of what is specified via the constructor so it's purely optional.  If using fstream, this is not the case and would need to be specified explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Checking out the Standard, section 27.8.1.3 discusses the various `ios` modifiers (like `ios::in` and `ios::out`), and maps them to the C `fopen()` parameters.  According to the Standard, if there are no modifiers specified on a file open, the open fails.

In 27.8.1.9, we find that `ofstream` works like that, but with `ios::out` automatically specified.  Therefore, the answer to the original question is that both will work exactly the same.

I don't know why people are finding that opening with an `fstream` without either `ios::in` or `ios::out`, but my reading of the Standard says it shouldn't work.  I'd be interested in other people's readings of 27.8.1.3.

Comment: where to find this standard??